# Timer doesn't work in java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, timer, freeze

I'm running a netbeans project and I want a 3 second timer to go off before moving to the next frame. However, when the button is pressed, nothing happens.

```
private void BeginTestButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int count = 3;
        while (count > 0) {
            try {
                CountdownToTest.setText(count + " ");
                CountdownToTest.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 32));
                CountdownToTest.setForeground(Color.RED);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                count--;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Section1 frame = new Section1();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you add the action to the listener? Have you try to put a system.out into beginTest method in order to see if the action is called?

Comment: There should *never* be a `sleep` in an event handler. Assuming this is Swing, you should use the [java.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class for timing operations.